# How to Label Equation with Tag by Number

Tags: equations, tag, labelling

For example, if I write a code as follows,

```
The equation with tag is \ldots
\begin{align}\label{E:1}
1 + \tan^2x & = 1 + {\sin^2x \over \cos^2x} \nonumber \\[5pt]
& = {\cos^2x + \sin^2x \over \cos^2x} \nonumber \\[5pt]
& = {1 \over \cos^2x} \tag*{by Lemma A} \nonumber \\[5pt]
& = \sec^2x.
\end{align}
Using \eqref{E:1}, we have \ldots
```

then it produces as follows.

[image]

What I intended is: "Using (1), we have ...", because (1) is the equation number.

How do I fix this incorrect labeling?

Thank you.

Comment: Try moving `\label` in the line where there's the equation number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're abusing `\tag`, in my opinion: readers will be confused about the meaning of the equation number.

Anyway, here's how you can do it: move the `\label` in the line where the equation number will appear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The equation with tag is
\begin{align}
1 + \tan^2x & = 1 + \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x} \notag \\
& = \frac{\cos^2x + \sin^2x}{\cos^2x} \notag \\
& = \frac{1\vphantom{\cos^2x}}{\cos^2x} \tag*{by Lemma A} \\
& = \sec^2x.\smash[b]{\vphantom{\frac{1}{\cos^2x}}} \label{E:1}
\end{align}
Using \eqref{E:1}, we have \ldots

\end{document}
```

I changed `\nonumber` to `\notag` (which is `amsmath` specific) and also changed `\over` to the LaTeX preferred format (there are several reasons to).

In order to fix the vertical spacing, I added a phantom (one smashed at the bottom).

[image]

How to make a better parenthetical remark?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The equation with tag is
\begin{equation}\label{E:1}
\begin{aligned}[b]
1 + \tan^2x & = 1 + \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x} \\
& = \frac{\cos^2x + \sin^2x}{\cos^2x} \\
& = \frac{1\vphantom{\cos^2x}}{\cos^2x} \makebox[2em][l]{\quad(by Lemma A)} \\
& = \sec^2x.\smash[b]{\vphantom{\frac{1}{\cos^2x}}} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Using \eqref{E:1}, we have \ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a 2em wide box doesn't influence too much the global centering.

Comment: Is the `\smash[b]` just so that you don't leave too much empty space below the displayed equation?

Comment: @WillieWong Yes; I need it to ensure uniform vertical space between the relation symbols, but it would add undesired vertical space at the bottom if not smashed.